# How to bypass CORS and get data from CORS blocked API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, cors

I am developing Spring boot app, i met a requirement where i need to request(get) a API which is already available in internet(developed by someone for demo purpose only) and get the data. but that API got CORS request blocked. though i can hit the api in browser and see the json response, i could not able to hit the API in my spring java code. i am getting 403 forbidden exception. is there anyway to solve this issue? Thanks

java code

```
String endPoint="www.api.blahblah.com"; (sample only)

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.getForEntity(endPoint+userName,String.class);
```

Comment: are you testing on localhost?

Comment: no, i have deployed to heroku

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data and bypass CORS you may need to use API with JSONP format

[JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

It's a JSON format with padding which allows you to request data from server residing in a different domain than yours.

If you are on localhost, you can disable CORS checking with extension appropriate to your browser (although it's not recommended) and still use external JSON API.

Here you have for instance Chrome extension to achieve this goal:
[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

I'm sure you get similar to that for other browsers too.

Comment: can use JSONP in java rest client? i thought this can be used with javascript only

Comment: This answer assumes you can control the server, which I think defeats the purpose of the question; if you control the server, you can probably add CORS support.

Answer (score 0):

The browser restricts access by design, unless the service provider allows it via CORS (or some alternative/hack like JSONP).

The only realistic option in this case is to proxy the API, i.e. setup your own intermediate server to transmit data between the 3rd party API to your client.

Answer (score 0):

`CORS` is a W3C spec that allows cross-domain communication from the browser. You don't need to bypass `CORS`. 
You need to by pass `Same Origin Policy` which is a restriction handled by a browser.

I was confused about that too, I recommend take a look at: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

But because you are making your request outside a browser `SOP` doesn't should be involved. I think you are receiving a forbidden error code for some other reason.

Check if the endpoint needs some special parameter, or if you have an example of a success request we can help you to find out how you reproduce it from java.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the open source program [Bypass Cors](https://chrishham.github.io/BypassCors/) , 
an installable Electron App (Windows/Mac/Linux), that lets you Bypass ALL CORS Restrictions permanently, 
by allowing you to set your own custom Headers (+Origin).

It is specifically designed to work with Web Apps and its perfect for Real Time Scraping.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the program.